# What To Consider Before Deploying A Meteor App?

Tags: meteor, web-deployment, jdeveloper

As I heard that there are many things need to be considered before Deploying a Meteor App, However, it's still quite vague. Anyone please give me some opinions about this issue. Thanks

Comment: When you say "deploying", do you mean "the app is built, what do we consider before deploying it?" or "we are considering creating a Meteor app, what should we take into account when deciding whether or not to use Meteor?"

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the wrong forum for this type of question, since it's highly opinionated and not really in the Q&A format, but I'll give you some of my personal opinions.

**Where am I hosting my app?**

This has a lot to do with what your app is (Web-based app, Android-only), how many users you plan to have, if this is a public app or something private, how much you have to spend, and many other factors.  Options include:

1. Host it yourself - Could be on a VPS (Virtual Private Server, like Digital Ocean and others), some cloud offering (AWS or similar), or a bare-metal server you have hosted somewhere (like in your closet).
2. Pay for dedicated hosting - Several out there that offer many different features, like Galaxy or Modulus, etc.

If you host it yourself, then you have to maintain the hosting solution, I.E you need to support it all on your own.  This may mean provisioning/installing the OS, installing and configuring the server apps (MongoDB, Node.js, web servers, etc), and maintaining everything over time.  The benefits, however, are potentially cheaper hosting costs (although this could be debated) and custom setups/architectures. If you are creating an app that should remain private (I.E. not a public app) you may want to consider this option so you can host it internal to the company and not make it public-facing.  There are some tools out there that can ease the process of setting up the server, for instance MUP/MUPX.

For dedicated Meteor hosting, the benefit is that someone else does the installation, configuration, and maintenance of the core apps, and all you have to do is push the button to move your code in.  These options can be more pricey as they are covering the IT costs of supporting the environment, but they usually come with the benefit that a) You don't have to install all that stuff yourself, b) you don't have to be an expert at all the "plumbing", c) You don't have to hire a staff of people to support your infrastructure, d) These hosting services usually know how to optimize things properly to get better performance for your app.

**Do I deploy manually or do I use some tool?**

This depends highly on the answer to #1, as your hosting decision may come with it's own set of tools used to deploy (ex. Galaxy), or you may need to shop around for the best tool for you.  For manual deploys, I'd suggest looking at MUP/MUPX, which can automate the deployment of your app, even configuring the web server, DB server, and setting up everything as Docker images.  Or, if you want to have more control, maybe take a look at something like Grunt or Gulp, which are more build-scripting solutions (similar to ANT/Maven/Gradle are for Java).

**Do I expect a fast growth, or a slow trickle?**

Again, this has a lot to do with where you plan to host.  Lots of cloud services make it easy to grow/shrink your cluster of servers based on load, but this takes a LOT of configuration past just installing an OS.  VPS and bare-metal solutions will be the hardest to expand.  Dedicated hosting will depend on the provider.

You need to serious need to think about how you might handle a fast-growth situation, even if you don't think your app will take off.  The internet is riddled with apps that failed because they didn't think they would be as successful as they were.  It only takes one mention on something like Reddit, Y Combinator, or Product Hunt for your app to get a sudden and unexpected rush of traffic that takes down the server(s). If you know your growth will be controlled in some way, like if you have a private app with a pre-set number of users, then you might not need to worry about it.

**Do I need to monitor my app?**

The answer to this is always "Yes", but to what extent?  Do you need to provide 24x7 uptime?  Would an outage cost you lots of money, make you loose your biggest client, etc?  Can the users live without service for a little while if it goes down, or would I loose face and customers?  Depending on how serious you need to be, you should consider some sort of monitoring of your infrastructure and app.  Again, there are LOTS of options here, and your decision might be swayed quite a bit by the answer to the first question.

I am sure there are other questions, but these are the biggest I could come up with.